# Why are my modules not importing after install?

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, bots

Im pretty new just trying to learn

[image: Debug info]

Im playing around with a trading bot on VSCODE and cant get a couple modules to import after installing them

```
type[{
    "resource": "/C:/Users/BILL/Documents/GitHub/TB105/traderlib.py",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": {
        "value": "reportMissingModuleSource",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "path": "/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "github.com",
            "fragment": "reportMissingModuleSource"
        }
    },
    "severity": 4,
    **"message": "Import \"pytz\" could not be resolved from source",**
    "source": "Pylance",
    "startLineNumber": 5,
    "startColumn": 23,
    "endLineNumber": 5,
    "endColumn": 27
}] here
```

reinstalled it

restarted vscode which has worked for some modules

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to ensure you have chosen the correct python interpreter which you installed the packages in. You can use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose the one.

Secondly, you have to ensure that you have install the package in the environment, you can use `pip show packagename` in the terminal to check it one by one.